# Lumia 925 with WP 8.1 keeps freezing

Tags: 8.1, lumia-925, soft-reset

Every so often my phone (Lumia 925, WP 8.1) dies and I have to do a soft reset and set up date and time manually because it's not working automatically (let's say my cellular provider is sucky I guess).

Freezes occur randomly, sometimes a few days in a row, some times once per week, while charging, while the phone is in the pocket, etc.

The biggest problem for me is if it dies during the night and the alarm doesn't go off.

It didn't crash while it was running WP 8.0.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Is this with the Nokia Cyan update, or the Developer Preview?

Comment: you can revert back to 8.0 and see if the freezing stops?

Comment: I believe it's Cyan, did a hard reset a month ago and got all the updates.

Comment: I can't revert to 8.0 atm, maybe in a month or so because I'm developing for work.

Comment: If you were to revert to 8.0 and the issue stopped then 8.1 could possibly be blamed, but it's more likely that 8.1 being installed exposed some sort of hardware issue with the phone.

Answer (score 2):

Micosoft has acknowledged the problem and promised to release a fix soon. 
http://www.windowscentral.com/struggling-lumia-925-lumia-1020-freezes-microsoft-will-soon-release-fix

PS: Will  update this answer as soon as i get news of the fix.

Answer (score 1):

I am myself facing this issue, moreover my sim doesnt works sometimes on lumia 925, and sometimes i get many sms copies instead of receiving only one original sms... 
It is a software issue most probably and Microsoft has acknowledged it, that wp 8.1 is doing problems in 925 and 1020 and they will release a fix soon with the next update of windows phone.
Link: 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpupdate/lumia-1020-phone-freezes-randomly-after-update-81/7d37ff28-1573-4be7-962e-25eb78d9bb56
and
http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-confirms-wp-81-freezing-issues-with-lumia-925-and-1020-patch-on-the-way

Answer (score 0):

If your Lumia 925 freezes and no button works anymore...even the power button.
There is annother way ( I never read about on the internet).

You can disconnect the battery connector ( theres one wire from the black battery) for a second, thats enough (just lift it up with a little screwdriver, and pull down and connect again) you will loose no data or apps. Nothing! 
it will automatically start up again.
No sweat.

Comment: Isn't the Lumia 925 a sealed design? How do you get access to the battery connector?